# Store Two Integer Multiplication Result not using int,Long,Double,String,BigDecimal in Java

Tags: java

So Question was like there is an method that is taking two int values as an parameters and we have to store the multiplication of those two integers but not in int,Long,Double,BigDecimal,String. The range of the result(multiplication) would be beyond from Integer range.

```
---- method(int a,int b){
      return a*b;
   }
```

So dashes in method signature denotes the desired return type that interviewer was exactly looking for.

Comment: Did you miss `BigInteger` in the list of return types not to be used?

Comment: Cant Use anything bigger from int and Integer too.

Comment: You can't use `Long`, but could you use `long`?

Comment: Please read my comment

Comment: what about a boolean array representating binary number?

Comment: Are you asking how to do multiplication without overflow?

Comment: Mind you, there is no point in returning anything other than `int`, considering that is the type of `a*b`. In other words: changing the return type from int is pointless, you've already lost the information.

Comment: @Lino that could be a solution but question is again how, what would be the size of that array

Comment: No I am asking with or without overflow, in both condition it should work

Comment: I am not getting Rude @Lino, see the Andy Tumer comment. I have problem thats why I am here.

Comment: @Ankit you told me to "sit silently" for asking a clarifying question, and making an observation about the semantics of the code in the question. Yes, you were rude.

Comment: I am sorry, I deleted that comment. If somebody get upset from my comment then again sorry

Comment: @AndyTurner, I have already said sorry for that and second thing, I clarified that question, it was not my question. Again sorry if u felt bad.

Comment: If you aren't trying to avoid overflow, then why does the return type have to be something other than `int`? Having been asked a question in an interview doesn't necessarily make it a good question.

Comment: There might be overflow.

Answer (score 1):

You could either use **long** primitive type or return **java.lang.Number** object type (which is supertype of all numeric boxed types in java):

```
public Number method(int a, int b){
    return (long)a * b;
}
```

Just note that you must cast either one of the variables to long.

**Attention:** This solution requires that the body of the method be modified!

Answer (score 1):

you could probably use the following snippet:

```
public boolean[] method(int a, int b){
    boolean[] bits = new boolean[64]; // max amount of long bits
    for(long l = 0, bit = 1; l < bits.length; l++){
        bits[(int) l] = (((long) a * b) & bit) == bit;
        bit <<= 1;
    }
    return bits;
}
```

This piece of code uses simple bit operations, to fill a boolean array which represents the product as bits. (`true` for `1`, `false` for `0`)

As you're never allowed to store the calculation anywhere. You need to calculate it everytime.

Comment: Multiplying `a*b` is an int, and bit shifting an int wraps after 32 bits. This won't work as written.

Comment: @AndyTurner you're right, may have a suggestion to remove the overflows? Casting one of the variables always to `long` or something?

Comment: yes, that would work.

Comment: @AndyTurner the array creation `boolean[] bits = new boolean[Long.bitCount((long) a * b)];` stills yields a too small array, maybe have an idea?

Comment: don't use bit count. It counts the number of *set* bits. There are other methods you could use, but why not just go for 64?

Comment: you're completly right. I updated the answer